# How to give numbers to markers in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

``In my requirement,I have a set of way points passed as json object to map. From those waypoints , the start and end have to shown in alphabets and the in-between markers should be in numbers. How can I implement this scenario?
 Also I found that google maps support a max of 8 wayspoints and one start and end .Is there any way to add more waypoints to my map? I am using google maps DirectionsService for waypoint renderng.

The code I used is

```
  function calcRoute() {
    var start = wayPointArray[0];
    var end = wayPointArray[1];
    var waypts = [];

    for (var i = 2; i <= wayPointArray.length-1; i++) {
            waypts.push({
                location: wayPointArray[i],

                stopover: true
            });

    }
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}

function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
```

wayPontArray contains all lats and long for the waypoints. The first and second will be the start and end respectively and all others are the waypoints. The start and end should be in alphabets ie A and B. The in between waypoints should be in numbers.

Thanks in advance
Boney.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the coordinates of your waypoints, you can use custom markers with numbers or lettersas labels as in [this example](http://biostall.com/adding-number-or-letters-to-google-maps-api-markers):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng, 
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|FF0000|000000'
});
```

Comment: Note that this feature of the Google Charts API is depracated as of April 20, 2012.

Comment: What is the current suggested way of doing this?